# Tag value is not parsed in Xml android pullParser

Tags: android, xml-parsing, android-xmlpullparser

I'm parsing an XML document. It's working fine. But one value is not get parsed. 
This is the xml document
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=Kataragama&mode=xml&units=metric&cnt=7

The **date** value is not parsed.

```
private String day="time";
public String getDay() {
        return day;
    }
public void parseXMLAndStoreIt(XmlPullParser myParser) {
          int event;
          String text=null;
          try {
             event = myParser.getEventType();
             while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                String name=myParser.getName();
                switch (event){
                   case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                   break;
                   case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                   text = myParser.getText();
                   break;

                   case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:



                      if(name.equals("time")){
                          day = myParser.getAttributeValue(null,"day");
                      }

                      else{
                      }
                      break;
                      }      
                      event = myParser.next(); 

                  }
                     parsingComplete = false;
          } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          }

       }
```

Main.java

```
day.setText(obj.getDay());
```

Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't you be retrieving the attribute when you encounter the `XmlPullParser.START_TAG`?

Comment: Could you please explain

Comment: Move the `if (name...` code part in the `case` for the `START_TAG`.

Comment: Are you performing any task in your else statement and other thing debug the value of day in your  if statement if(name.equals("time")){
                          day = myParser.getAttributeValue(null,"day");
                      }

                      else{
                      }

Answer (score 0):

Its because your `if(name)` condition is in your switch block.
Remove the `case XmlPullParser.START_TAG`OR:

```
String day=null;

        try {
              while (myParser.getEventType()!= XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                      if(myParser.getEventType()==XmlPullParser.START_TAG && myParser.getName().equals("time")
                        day= myParser.getAttributeValue(null,"day");  
        }
     }catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
    day= myParser.getAttributeValue(0);}
```